# Python Threaded Vs Non Threaded

Tags: python, multithreading

I am currently experimenting with a Python zipfile password cracker, which is multi-threaded. I thought a new thread is like a new connection/instance, basically getting the job done faster, only when i removed threading and timed the differences I am left shocked with the apparent drop in performance (x6 slower). I will insert the code here in case that's the issue.

```
import zipfile
from threading import Thread

def extractFile(zFile, password):
    try:
        zFile.extractall(pwd=password)
        print '[+] Password:', password
    except:
        pass

def main():
    zFile = zipfile.ZipFile('encrypted.zip')
    passFile = open('dictionary.txt', 'r')
    for line in passFile.readlines():
        password = line.strip('\n')
        t = Thread(target=extractFile, args=(zFile,password))   
        t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Once I remove threading it completes 6 times faster. The time results are:

#### Threaded

```
real    18m46.974s 
user    18m25.936s   
sys     9m6.872s
```

#### Non threaded

```
real    3m32.674s
user    3m6.400s
sys     0m25.664s
```

Why is this happening? I expected that using a multi-threaded approach would improve performance.

Comment: "threading is supposed to increase performance" is not true as a general rule, and particularly not in CPython (where the Global Interpreter Lock limits what can be done in parallel).

Comment: ...there are certainly cases where threading *can* increase performance, but they depend very much on the details of your workload and your hardware. It's not magic pixie dust guaranteed to increase performance in any language.

Comment: [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)

Comment: _"I thought a new thread is like a new connection/instance"_. Maybe you're thinking of the `multiprocessing` module, which does spawn new processes, and is not affected by the GIL.

Comment: it's pretty straightforward: in python, `threading` can only speed up I/O bound tasks (like fetching a bunch of webpages).  It will only slow down your CPU-bound tasks (like crunching zipfiles, or calculating digits of pi) due to involved overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with this approach:

1) You are spawning N threads, where N is the number of lines in dictionary.txt. Based on the number of lines I'm guessing there are in dictionary.txt, that means you're spawning thousands of threads in a tight loop. Having that many threads running simultaneously is a huge resource drain, because each thread takes up some memory, and your CPU can only actually run a few threads at a time (actually, in Python it can only run one thread at a time, more on that in #2). There is also a cost to actually spawning a thread, and spawning that many is going to slow you down.

2) Because of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), in Python only one thread can actually execute at a time. This the negates the benefit of a multi-core CPU, which should allow you to process multiple threads at a time. You should instead use the [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html) module, specifically the Pool class, to parallelize. It will allow you to take advantage of multiple cores, and using a Pool will prevent you from spawning thousands of processes and grinding your system a halt.

Comment: thank you, care to update the script so it utilizes multiprocessing?

Comment: The answer is wrong: The GIL is not a problem. For inflating (the actual uncompressing) multithreading is possible, because it is a pure C function which is bracketed `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` and `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS`. The problem in your case is, that you try to read **one** file at many random positions at once. This increases your system load and slows down the whole process.